# Division for two arbitrary precision binary integers

Tags: c, arbitrary-precision

I've got two integer numbers in binary form, `num1` and `num2` stored as strings containing "0"s and "1"s.

What would be the best algorithm to divide `num1` by `num2` in order to obtain a floating-point `double` result?

Comment: Maximum size of strings?

Comment: @keith Character quantity is arbitrary but `size(string1) == size(string2)` is always true

Comment: The term ‘string’ has different meanings in each of the three languages. Which are you really working with?  How do you represent a floating point value in your system?  How do you know where the binary point is?  How many digits in the result?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler C null-terminated string

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Floating point numbers are represented as 8 bytes long `double`

Comment: I would think converting the values to units of the machine word size and then simply implementing the by-hand long division algorithm. Stop when you have enough result bits to fill your FP result type.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir "by-hand long division algorithm"?

Comment: Define "best". Performance wise? Simplicity of writing? Precision? I'd bet that converting them into doubles and writing `n1/n2` would be simple and efficient.

Comment: I would just convert to `base 10` and do the division regularly using `doubles`. Why use `1` and `0` to divide?

Comment: In my opinion it's much easier to make a base 2 to base 10 converter and then do the division than it is to make a binary dividing function.

Comment: @Ivan86 - Why does base 10 need to be involved here?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Since they are integers in binary form why not just convert them to decimal and then do the operation. Otherwise if he wished to do this in binary [this](https://www.wikihow.com/Divide-Binary-Numbers) would be useful.

Comment: He would need a function for division and a function for subtraction of binary numbers.

Comment: @Ivan86 - I guess you mean parse the values to `[long] int` or whatever?  That doesn't involve decimal, though.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Sorry about that I meant `base 10` (decadic) not decimal.

Comment: @Ivan86 - It doesn't involve base 10, either ;)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Sorry if I was unclear but both the answers below say what I was saying. It is not binary division though.

Comment: @Ivan86 - Sure.  All I'm saying is that there's no decimal/base10 involved anywhere here.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I understand, but I don't see an advantage to binary division over regular division so that's why I added that comment. There are some good methods to divide decimal numbers with practically arbitrary precision.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Something like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22146/implement-arbitrary-precision-division).

Comment: `double quotient = 1.0L * strtoumax(num1, 0,2)/strtoumax(num1, 0,2);` is a start.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your strings are in big-endian binary format, which is the most natural way to represent a binary number as a string, here is how you could convert each `str` to a double `val`:

```
double val = 0.0;
while (0 != *str) {
    val *= 2.0;
    if ('1' == *str) val += 1.0;
    str++;
}
```

Then divide the doubles.

Comment: or `val = val*2 + (*str - '0');`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
int stringToNum(std::string str){
  int num=0;
  for(size_t i=0;i<str.size();i++){
    if(str[i]=='1'){num+=pow(2,str.size()-i-1);}
  }
 return num;
}

int main(){
   std::string str1,str2;
   std::cin>>str1>>str2;
   int num1 = stringToNum(str1);
   int num2 = stringToNum(str2);
   std::cout << (float)num1/num2 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: if you want to get the double value, just change the float to double, it should just work

Answer (score 0):

Code could follow primary school math.

```
Align the dividend and divisor.  
Loop DOUBLE_BITS times  
  Test divisor and dividend  
  If big enough, subtract and add to quotient   
  Shift
```

Below is *untested* code, so treat as pseudo-code to OP an idea of a solution.

```
double str_div(const char * num1, const char *num2) {
  while (*num1 == '0') num1++;  // find ms bit
  while (*num2 == '0') num2++;
  if (*num2 == '\0') {
    if (*num1) return 1.0/0.0;
    return 0.0/0.0; 
  }
  size_t sz1 = strlen(num1) + 1;
  size_t sz2 = strlen(num2) + 1;
  double m = pow(2, 1.0* sz1 - sz2);
  #define DOUBLE_BITS 53
  size_t szmx = max(sz1, sz2); 
  size_t sza = szmx  + DOUBLE_BITS + 1;

  // form working register `a`
  char *a = malloc(sza);
  memset(a, '0', sza);
  memcpy(a, num1, sz1 - 1);
  a[sz1 - 1] = '\0';
  double quotient = 0.0;
  for (size_t i=0; i<DOUBLE_BITS; i++) {
    if (str_ge(a, num2)) {  // a >= num2?
      str_sub(a, num2);     // a -= num2
      quotient += m; 
    }
    m /= 2.0;
  }
  free(a);
  return quotient;
}
```